# Knockout binding handler pass array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, data-binding, knockout-es5-plugin

Is it possible to pass array value with square brackets for binding handler?, ie:

```
<div data-bind="validator: [{class: RequiredValidator}, {class: EmailValidator}]"></div>
```

It works fine for one object:

```
<div data-bind="validator: {class: RequiredValidator}"></div>
```

Class value is not observable, just javascript object.

It throws `Message: Unexpected token )` error.

Or I need some other syntax? I could wrap it with object, but prefer not.

I took snapshot of project with this issue, available here: http://balin.maslosoft.com/array-validators/dev/validator.php

Open console, and object validators will show configuration, while array will fail.

Here is fiddle with minimal example: http://jsfiddle.net/piotr/fu8d0hm3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was problem with [knockout-es5](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-es5/) modification for [two-way bindings](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-es5/issues/2).

Original plugin is not affected. I've created [pull request](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-es5/pull/48) to address this issue.

The problem was binding preprocessing, which produced invalid code if array value was passed.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to set a **VALID** `value` to the `key` you are passing . As in you case `RequiredValidator` is not defined so keep that in quotes to resolve the issue .

**view:**

```
<div data-bind="validator: [{class: 'RequiredValidator'}, {class: 'EmailValidator'}]"></div>
```

**viewModel:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.validator = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    console.log(valueAccessor()); //check console window for o/p
  }
}
ko.applyBindings();
```

check sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/s3QTU/654/)**

Comment: In ko quotes are not nessesary, ie. `validator: {class: RegExpValidator}` works fine. Your example works too. However in my case it does not work even with quotes, weird.

Comment: ok i get it @PeterM . so you need set `valid value` to key value pairs . ex: class:hello is undefined where as class:'hello' works fine ,

Comment: Yes, I have valid value. I've uploaded full example here: http://balin.maslosoft.com/array-validators/dev/validator.php open console for results.

Answer (score 2):

It works for these. Might the problem be in your binding handler?

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.validator = {
  init: function(el, va) {
    var value = va();
    console.debug(value);
  }
};

vm = {
  something: ko.observable('hi')
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="validator: ['one']"></div>
<div data-bind="validator: [something()]"></div>
<div data-bind="validator: [{class: something()}, {class:'whatever'}]"></div>
```

Comment: It works here. But for some reason it doesn't work in my project. Here is snapshot available http://balin.maslosoft.com/array-validators/dev/validator.php - open console for output of validator binding handler.

Comment: Your `with` bindings are failing because you're using "app.model" when the app structure is outside your viewmodel.

Comment: `app` is global variable, it is accessible. Try for example type something in first input and then check in console: `app.model.txt1.text`. Knockout fails clearly at `validator: [...`.

Comment: The first message in the console is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to process binding "with: function (){return ko.getObservable($data,"app.model.txt3")||app.model.txt3 }"
Message: Unable to parse bindings.

Comment: What is the `htmlValue` binding? Should that be `html`?

Comment: It is two-way binding for conteneditable div, it's irelevant here. I know that error message is confusing. As there is not even `(` token in binding. Notice that first 3 console outputs are proper validator config, while 4th validator for **Validate contenteditable if it's not empty and valid email:** fails.

Comment: @PeterM I think we're back to the problem being in the `validator` binding handler, which is unfortunately complicated, but does not seem to accept an array.

Comment: `init` function is very simple, it only `console.log ` - depending if it's function  - `ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())` or `ko.unwrap(valueAccessor)`. It does not even come to this statement. Maybe it's some problem with es5 plugin.

Comment: It turn out to be es5 plugin problem... Newer version works fine.

Comment: While this does not answer questions, your comments pointed me in right directions, thanks.